# How can I execute a command to each file in a directory?

Tags: powershell

I want to view what's inside each pak of an Unreal Engine 4 game. In the game files there are like 700+ paks, and execute the command to view the content manually it's just a pain.

I'm using Unreal Engine's `UnrealPak.exe` to view the contents of a pak file.
I use the next command to view (and log) the contents of a pak-

```
E:\UE_4.10\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealPak.exe (directory of the game)\Content\Paks\(pak file name).pak -test > C:\Users\(user)\Desktop\Logs\log.txt
```

This will put all the output of that command in the log.txt textfile.

What I want to do is a loop that will execute that command to each file, and then I could do two things, have one `log.txt` and then put all the outputs of all the paks in there, or have `log_(pakname).txt`

I could just go manually, but it's going to take a lot of time to execute the same command 700+ times. If someone can help me, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question, in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path. -Recurse -Include  "*.pak" | Foreach-Object { invoke-expression "E:\UE_4.10\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealPak.exe $($_.Fullname) -test " | Out-file "log.txt" -Append}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's add unrealpak to the path:

```
$env:path += E:\UE_4.10\Engine\Binaries\Win64
```

Then

```
cd somedir\Content\Paks
dir *.pak | foreach { unrealpak $_ -test >> ~\desktop\log.txt }
```